# Group by language in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to see the data on **Demographic -> Language** grid grouped by ISO 3316 language, without differences between the (optional) ISO639 country code national variant.

For example, instead of seeing:

```
| Language | Visits |
|----------|--------|
| it       | 56,027 |
| it-it    | 35,130 |
| en-us    | 5,878  |
| en       | 1,211  |
| es       | 897    |
| es-es    | 576    |
| ...      | ...    |
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
| Language | Visits |
|----------|--------|
| it       | 91,157 |
| en       | 7,089  |
| es       | 1473   |
|----------|--------|
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Solved! I simply used the "Country/Territory" column as primary dimension on that report!

Comment: That's not at all the same. Country/Territory is the user's location, based on their IP (or other information). Language is the one they installed their browser in (e.g. the browser's menu-language). These two might relate, but travellers will be identified wrong and depending on country it might be just completely misleading.

Comment: ISO639 does not define any subtags, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an advanced filter at the profile level that will search and replace the language input field and keep only the first 2 letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original language variations in your reports, you'll need to [define your own dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en#set_up_custom_dimensions) and use the tracking code (or Google Tag Manager) to fill it from the browser's language setting:

```
// this will extract 'it' from 'it-IT' or 'it-CH'
var primaryLanguage = navigator.language.match(/[^-]+/)[0];

ga('set', 'dimension1', primaryLanguage);
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

HTTP uses the [IEFT Language Tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag), so the primary language can be provided in different standards. It can consist of up to 8 letters. This usually won't be the case, but if you need to account for this, you need some extra logic to group languages from different standards.